# Simple question on using Equivalence relation property to solve an equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Question:
Determine all pairs of integers A,B such that (m,n)∼(u,v)⟺m−An=Bu−v

is an equivalence relation on the set of all pairs of integers.

My attempt:
I had worked out that there are 2 pairs of A, B that satisfies the above equivalence relation, namely (A, B) = (v/n, m/u) and (m/n, v/u). But it seems that it isn't correct.

Why it is wrong and how to solve the question? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give more insight? Are all variables integers? To be honest, I have not really read your post. The first thing that strikes out is, that it is unclear why (v/n, m/u) should be a pair of integers.

Comment: Actually it's my homework question, and the question is exactly the same as the one i had posted above. My teacher's comment for my answer is that m and n are not defined variables, but then, i don't know how to work out the correct answer, i.e. can we really find out some integer A, B as concrete as like stating A = 1, B = 2(just an example)? Or just a pair of A, B in terms of variables?

Comment: "I had worked out that there are 2 pairs of A, B that satisfies the above equivalence relation, namely (A, B) = (v/n, m/u) and (m/n, v/u)" But $m,n,u,v$ are not constants.

Comment: $\frac vn$ *isn't* a number and neither $v$ nor $n$ is constant.  This must be true if $v=2$ and $n = 39$ then $\frac vn$ will be a different number that if $v=-2345$ and $n=13$.

Comment: "can we really find out some integer A, B as concrete as like stating A = 1, B = 2(just an example)? Or just a pair of A, B in terms of variables?"  Yes.  Yes.. You can.  Note that $\sim$ must be reflexive.  So we must have for *EVERY* $m,n$ that $m-An=Bm-n$ for *EVERY* $(m,n)$.   What does that tell us.  $329 - 27A = 329B -27$ for example.  *And we must have $1-A = B-1$ and we must have $5-3A=5B-3$.... and so on....

Comment: Thanks for the hints! They are useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's reflexive so we must have $(m,n)\sim(m,n)$ or $m-An=Bm-n$ for all $m,n$.  So $(1-B)m=(A-1)n$ for *all* $m,n$.  If  $1-B \ne 0$ then $\frac {A-1}{1-B} = \frac mn$ for all $m,n; n\ne 0$. But that's impossible as $\frac {A-1}{1-B}$ would be a constant. So $1-B=0$ and $B=1$ and $(A-1)n=0$ for all $n$.  So $A-1=0$ and $A=1$.

Those are the only case that makes $\sim$ reflexive. So $(m,n)\sim(u,v) \iff m-n=u-v$.

So that is the *only* possible answer.  But we have to show that that *is* an answer and that $(m,n)\sim(u,v) \iff m-n = u-v$ *is* an equivalence.

We have to show that is an equivalence relation.  It's reflexive and $m-n= m-n$ for all $m,n$.

Is it symmetric?  If $m-n = u-v \implies u-v = m-n$?  Yes.  So it is symmetric.

Is it transitive?  If $m-n = u-v$ and $u-v = w-z$ does that imply $m-n=w-z$.  Yes it does.  so it is transitive.